# Can't figure out how to use newer version of g++ in Centos 6 Docker image

Tags: docker, centos, devtoolset

I have a Docker image that is used for running tests in Jenkins and Bamboo. I need to upgrade the version of `g++` used (to something with C++11 support).

I tried using a Dockerfile that looks roughly like the following one:

```
FROM docker.blahblahblah/centos/6.6:latest

RUN yum install -y git gcc-c++ imake centos-release-scl-rh devtoolset-7-toolchain

# I've tried putting this into /etc/bashrc, ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo "source scl_source enable devtoolset-7" >> ~/.bashrc
```

My issue is that when `g++` is used within the container, it uses the older one, instead of the newer one in `devtoolset-7`, even though the newer one should be sourced from the bashrc. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding how Docker will try to run everything.)

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `centos:6.6` in dockerhub even do not have `devtoolset-7-toolchain`. So this is your private repo, then you need to afford more information. E.g. How you verify it use the old one, not the new one. From `exec` or just use `CMD`, and what's your `CMD` or `Entrypoint` look like, these all related to your matter.

Comment: @atline I verify it's using the old version of because I added a `g++ --version` in a few places and confirmed it's the old version instead of the newer devtools one. `g++` is actually called from a  python script that runs inside the Docker container which calls `make` which calls `g++`. The container has no `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to this otherwise valid question are quite poor so necromancing this question...

**In your Dockerfile**

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.2-devel-centos7
...
RUN yum -y install centos-release-scl-rh
RUN yum -y install scl-utils devtoolset-7
...
COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**entrypoint script**

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... do some setup ...
# then run the CMD passed as command-line arguments

scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
exec "$@"
```

Then, when you run:

[image: g++ version responds as expected]

Comment: I barely remember what I was working on when I first asked this question, but hopefully this answer will be useful to someone in the future :)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso : perhaps consider marking it as the solution ;)